# Why is there only one angle of incidence that gives minimum deviation in prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics

On plotting the angle of deviation vs the angle of incidence for a prism, we find that the graph dips only at one point. It is this result that is later used to prove that for minimum deviation to occur in a prism, the angle of incidence must be equal to the angle of emergence.

But why exactly does the graph have only one minima? Are there any mathematical or physical reasons behind this phenomenon, or is it a purely empirical result?

Comment: an at least twice differentiable smooth function can only have isolated (discrete) singular points, such as local minima and maxima.

Comment: @hyportnex Why do we need to differentiate it twice? we are differentiating only once right?

Comment: In analysis there is a result called "Sard's theorem", I hope I am not misinterpreting it, my memory maybe fading, according to which the singular points have measure zero for a smooth function, but another derivative would make that set discrete.